# single Insert query to insert multiple rows in one column

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a query that will insert multiple values from my form into a single row in my table.

```
 $q2="INSERT INTO tbl_Answer('Answer')VALUES ('$A1'),('$A2'),('$A3'),('$A4'),('$A5')";
```

Everything I have found tells me this should work using PHP with a MySQl database. Any ideas if I have done something wrong with the syntax or where my issue is? Thanks

Comment: So, what is the problem? Do you get an error somewhere?

Comment: it depends in what's in the $An variables

Comment: Are you trying to a) insert values into multiple rows but the same column, or b) insert values into multiple columns in the same row? Your title and the description in your question sound like two different operations.

Comment: Im looking to add multiple rows in my 'answer' column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We might need more information however a couple of things:

- If you are using mysql in `unix` based system tables are case sensitive.
- Second, should you use ` instead of ' on the name of your columns?(and i would say they are both innecesary) like:

  INSERT INTO tbl_Answer(`Answer`) or even better INSERT INTO tbl_Answer(Answer)

Comment: My issue was that I was using ' and I needed to be using ` for my column names. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Answer (Answer) VALUES ('$A1'),('$A2'),('$A3'),('$A4'),('$A5')
```

Is the same as saying:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Answer (Answer) VALUES ('$A1')    
INSERT INTO tbl_Answer (Answer) VALUES ('$A2')
INSERT INTO tbl_Answer (Answer) VALUES ('$A3')
INSERT INTO tbl_Answer (Answer) VALUES ('$A4')
INSERT INTO tbl_Answer (Answer) VALUES ('$A5')
```

What exactly are you looking for?

Here is a demo of your original query working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e20fc/1

Looks like the value of $A1-$A5 is throwing the query off. Are you receiving any error?

Comment: I'm looking for exactly that however my syntax is not working as it stands

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($A1);`?

Answer (score -2):

You need more fields in your table. You should have a field for each of your variables.

You have a minor problem with your query syntax.

```
$q2 = "INSERT INTO tbl_Answer
        ('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5')
       VALUES
        ('$A1', '$A2', '$A3', '$A4', '$A5');";
```

Comment: Well, there will be multiple rows created each time you run an INSERT INTO query. The problem is that you cannot insert five variables into one column ('Answer') unless you want to [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) your results first. And your parentheses of your VALUES statement were invalid.

Comment: You are not answering his question.