# Insert multiple values in table using single sql Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can i insert multiple values in a sql table using single statement. Doing in sql server 2008

Comment: Any particular RDBMS and version?

Comment: Here is a question search before posting.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232419/single-insert-query-to-insert-multiple-rows-in-one-column

Comment: you can also use this query to insert multiple rows in single statment:-INSERT into TABLE1(a, b, c) SELECT 1, 'New York','Sam' UNION SELECT 2, 'London','John'  UNION SELECT 3, 'Paris',James'  UNION SELECT 4, 'Munich', 'Krish'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`INSERT INTO ... VALUES` allows you to add multiple rows of data to your table in one statement. For MySQL, e.g., you can find the syntax diagram [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html).

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (`col1`, `col2`) 
VALUES ( 'val1', 'val2' ), 
       ( 'val3', 'val4' );
```

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server 2008 you can insert multiple rows using a single SQL INSERT statement.

```
INSERT INTO Table ( Column1, Column 2 ) VALUES
( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 )
```

For reference to this have a look at MOC Course 2778A - Writing SQL Queries in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do an insertion from a query

```
INSERT INTO Table (Column1, Column2)
SELECT Value1, Value2 FROM OtherTable
```

It will Insert into the Table all the values returned by the SELECT query